# Сообщения на всех клиентах

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Доброе время суток. Требуется сделать систему, состоящую из администратора и клиентов. Т.е. это будет сайт, на котором находятся пользователи. Администратор или по клику по кнопке, или по команде в командной строке вызывает функцию на стороне клиентов, (я так понял, тут нужен ajax) а функция в свою очередь что то делает (например всплывающее окно, главное что бы у все кто на сайте оно отображалось). У всех клиентов в свою очередь всплывает это окно (например с вариантом (да/нет)). Как можно реализовать систему что бы выполнялась функция у всех пользователей? Огромная просьба помочь. В какую сторону капать хотя бы подскажите.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можете привести пример 2х страниц? На 1й кнопка, при нажатии, на 2й странице показывается div с текстом например. Спасибо.

Comment: А почему нужно так сложно? Нельзя ли в каждой странице клиента поставить код таймера например. Или вы хотите попрактивоватся с Ajax, javascript. Да на ajax лучше

Comment: @MrGons18, стоит задача сделать такую систему, + практика для себя. у меня была мысль сделать так: видел где то что через ajax делается запрос в БД, если есть новые сообщения, они выводятся... вот думаю, если к кнопке(что на 1й странице) сделать функцию записи в БД, а у клиента, что бы проверял постоянно (как вы говорите по таймеру) наличие новой записи в БД, и если есть - выполнять js функцию у клиента.
UPD.: Не отрицаю что это бред...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Comet](http://goo.gl/Yc1o3):

> Comet (в веб-разработке) — любая модель работы веб-приложения, при которой постоянное HTTP-соединение позволяет веб-серверу отправлять (push) данные браузеру без дополнительного запроса со стороны браузера.

[Polling](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128535/):

> Сейчас довольно популярно использование Comet-технологии, «когда при которой постоянное HTTP-соединение позволяет веб-серверу отправлять (push) данные браузеру, без дополнительного запроса со стороны браузера», согласно википедии. Реализаций этой технологии есть много разных, но я сейчас хочу остановиться на одной из них, которая называется Long Polling.

Comment: т.е. Long Polling можно реализовать и на js, ajax, php?

Comment: совершенно верно!